# How to apply deformable transformation of 3D points using ANTs registration

Tags: python, registration

"I have used ANTs registration to register two MRI images (nifty files), resulting in the generation of `0GenericAffine.mat` and `1Warp.nii.gz` files containing the affine matrix and deformation field, respectively. Now, I need to transform a set of 3D points using these files. I attempted to use `antsApplyTransformsToPoints`, but the results are not reliable. Can anyone suggest an alternative method or provide guidance on how to properly use these files for transforming 3D points?"